# Publishing Flutter Web App to Firebase Hosting: recent changes not published

Tags: firebase, build, flutter-web, codemagic

My Codemagic pipeline is configured to fetch sources from my repository, build web and publish it to Firebase hosting.

The build is each time successful, but the changes from my last commit are not there, so I assume that the publishing part somehow not woking properly.

In the logs though everything looks great, my last commit is fetched, and firebase logs say that deploy is complete with the link to the site and all. (see below)

How could I "Debug" this case,  any ideas on what is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try following steps to debug such type of issues:

1. open site in incognito mode to ensure issue not related to browser cache
2. check `Cache-Control` and `Date` response headers for `main.dart.js` file to ensure you have properly configured cache behaviour in Firebase Hosting

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers

I hope it will help